# Google Play Store not showing Update on app (android)

Tags: android, google-play

***Introduction***

I have uploaded my first version of app and users downloaded it , installed it and used too. It was a cake. But when i upload the second version then it gets updated after 1 hour or so.

***Problem***

It is showing version update in google play when I open it in Mac. But when I search for it in the android device its not showing the upgraded version or the to update dialog. So I wait for 12 hours or so by thinking the listing might be not done yet. But still no result. And when I clear the cache of google play in android it shows to update.

***Question***

Why does this happen? Is there any solution that the update button will immediately come then the app is updated and published in play store.

Please do attach any official docs if available.

***Update***

i figured out the google play in the android device is the problem. if i clear the cache then google play detects the new version and prompts to update the app. so is there any way to programmatically clear cache of google play in android.

Comment: It just takes time to publish throughout the play store. You can't force it to update everywhere immediately.

Comment: so this happens with every app ?

Comment: Yes, it happens to everyone.

Comment: i can see this updated version on playstore on mac . but not in android ? so why android cant be aware of this ?whats the problem .

Comment: try to clear cache or clear data your play store. it works for me

Comment: `Have you tried to turn it off and on again?`  It will take some time to update all clusters from Google backend service.  There is no guarantee that your request from Mac is served in the same cluster with your Android Google Play app's request.

Comment: turn on and off what ? android device or google play ?

Comment: yes i did so @Rainey  and i told so in question . but no user have enough time to clear cache every time a new update comes .the play store should automatically and immediately detect it . right ?

Comment: is your device listed as compatible with the new version of your app?

Comment: yes . it is @Bhargav

Comment: You have to change device and install. check it

Comment: what do you mean ? i dint get you @RaviVaghela

Comment: try to install in other mobile and check that in you can get updated application.?

Comment: this is the same case in other device. i am testing on  5 devices at a time @RaviVaghela

Comment: ohk. then rest for some time may get change from google other wise you have to mail support.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106308/discussion-between-ravi-vaghela-and-sagar-nayak).

Answer (score 1):

The best fix for this in these times are [In-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates)

[image]

Also Google Play caching is got better over time, now it is not a big problem as it was before.